# Pgadmin query result vs application query result has added text

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, postgis, react-leaflet

I have nearly a thousand features in a table in my database that I want to query and aggregate as a single feature collection in a geojson file which I'm successfully doing using the following query:

```
SELECT jsonb_build_object(
    'type',     'FeatureCollection',
    'features', jsonb_agg(features.feature)
)
FROM(
    SELECT jsonb_build_object(
    'type',       'Feature',
    'id',         parcelid,
    'geometry',   ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_GeometryN(geom,1))::jsonb,
    'properties', to_jsonb(inputs) - 'parcelid' - 'geom'
) as feature 
    FROM (SELECT * FROM parcels2020) inputs) features;
```

When I use this query in pgadmin, everything is queries fine a, a brief example of the result is

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"id":"14F0035  LL0435","type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","etc
```

However when I use my application to perform this same query my result has the text "json_build_object" added to it like the example below.

```
[{"json_build_object":{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"id":"14F0035  LL0435","type":"Feature","geometry"etc
```

This is stopping me from being able to map the geometries of my parcels since the json is no longer being seen as a valid json. Is there a way to perform my query and not get additional text

Comment: Most likely `json_build_object` is in this case the name of the column from your select ;)

Comment: It 100% is I realized yesterday and it's wrapping my entire result in that but I need a way to do this query without the wrapping/column name

Comment: Not sure if this will help you, but you can remove the outer json Object with "- 'jsonb_build_object'" after your first select.